# if it possible to automatically #include guards in Sublime?

Tags: include-guards

I typically work with a lot of header (.h) files in Sublime tex editor and it would be very helpful if there was a way to automate the inclusion of:

```
#ifndef _STUFF_H_
#define _STUFF_H_
//some stuff

#endif
```

Does anyone know of a way to automatically do this so that everytime I start a .h file in Sublime, it would automatically include the #ifndef, #define, #endif?